# Переадресация на субдомен, кроме нескольких IP

Tags: .htaccess

Значит, что хотел сделать... Сейчас сайт перенаправляет с domen.com на domen.com/empty.html, кроме определенных IP. Как переписать так, чтобы перенаправлял с domen.com на sub.domen.com для всех, кроме тех же IP?

Сейчас записано так:
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^(0.0.0.0|1.1.1.1|2.2.2.2)
RewriteRule ^.* index.html [L]
RewriteRule ^index.php$ - [L]

Answer (score 0):

Ответ:
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^(0.0.0.0|1.1.1.1|2.2.2.2)
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domen.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://sub.domen.com/$1 [R=302,L]